# How to use awk to generate fixed width columns with colored input?

Tags: bash, awk, ls

I am taking the output from 'ls -l' and passing it through awk to reformat it.
This works:

```
list=$(ls --color=none -l | tail -n+2)
printf '%s' "$list" | awk '{printf "%-40s more stuff\n", $9}'
```

It produces something like:

```
env_profiles                             more stuff
ls_test.sh                               more stuff
saddfasfasfdfsafasdf                     more stuff
test                                     more stuff
```

But with --color=always it produces:

```
env_profiles                 more stuff
ls_test.sh                   more stuff
saddfasfasfdfsafasdf             more stuff
test                             more stuff
                                         more stuff
```

"env_profiles" is a directory, "ls_test.sh" is an executable file, so they are both colored and end up with different alignment. Also there is an extra line.

EDIT: Modified answer based on Ed Morton's post. Gets rid of extra line, handles filenames with spaces:

```
ls --color=always -l | tail -n+2 | awk '
{
    $1=$2=$3=$4=$5=$6=$7=$8=""
    field = substr($0,9)
    nameOnly = $0
    gsub(/\x1b[^m]+m/,"",nameOnly)
    if( length(field) - length(nameOnly) >= 0 ) {
        printf "%-*s more stuff\n", 40 + length(field) - length(nameOnly), field
    }
}'
```

Comment: The _colored_ input contains escape sequences.  So it's _different_ from what it appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field ($9) that contains your colored file names starts and ends with control characters to produce the color on your terminal, e.g. in this case `foo` is colored on the screen but `bar` is not:

```
$ cat o1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 emorton Domain Users     21591 Nov 12  2011 foo
-rwxr-xr-x  1 emorton Domain Users     21591 Nov 12  2011 bar

$ cat -v o1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 emorton Domain Users     21591 Nov 12  2011 ^[[01;32mfoo^[[0m
-rwxr-xr-x  1 emorton Domain Users     21591 Nov 12  2011 bar
```

so when you printf that field in awk and give it a field width of N characters, the color-producing strings are counted as part of the width but then if they are non-printing or backspaces or whatever then the end result will not not show them and it'll look like it's using less space a field that did not contain those characters. Hope that makes sense.

It looks to me like the coloring strings always start with the character `\x1b` then some coloring instruction and end with `m` so try this:

```
$ awk '{
    nameOnly = $NF
    gsub(/\x1b[^m]+m/,"",nameOnly)
    printf "<%-*s>\n", 10 + length($NF) - length(nameOnly), $NF
}' o1
<foo       >
<bar       >
```

Note that your approach of using a specific field only works if there's no spaces in the file names

Answer (score 0):

```
ls --color=always -l | tail -n+2 | awk '{count = gsub(/\x1b/, "\x1b"); if (count == 0) count += 40; else count += 50; printf "%-"count"s more stuff\n", $9}'
```

### Explanation

`gsub` returns the number of substitutions made on a line. In this case we are substituting the escape character `\x1b` with itself, storing the number of times it appears.

If there were no escape sequences found (`count == 0`) we add 40 spaces of padding.
If there *were* escape sequences on the line (ie. color), we add 40 spaces of padding **plus an additional 10 spaces**. And of course, `count` is already equal to the number of escapes.

I found that on my system, if a line has color, it requires 10 more spaces of padding, plus the number of escape characters to match the uncolored lines. For example: normal padding = 40; there were 3 escape sequence on the line; padding should be 40 + 10 + 3 = 53. This may be different on your system and may require adjustment of the numbers.

Finally, we print the line, substituting `count` for the padding.

Comment: did not work for me, as even the uncolored lines have \x1b chars (at least on my setup, MinGW/MSYS)